# Trouble installing the haxe language binding in monodevelop

Tags: monodevelop, haxe

Good morning.

I am trying to setup haxe development tools in monodevelop as shown [in this tutorial.](http://www.joshuagranick.com/blog/?p=758)

My problem is i can't find the [haxe language binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFV5v.png) the in add-in manager.

Does anyone know the solution to this issue?

Best regards

Guilherme Silva

Comment: The best alternative is to use FlashDevelop ide. It has built in support for haxe and nme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even the haxe binding dated 14/3/2013 only works for Monodevelop 3.0. I was able to download Monodevelop 3.0.6 from sourceforge. If it still doesn't work through the add-in manager, you can manually download it (link below) and install by file.

resources:
http://addins.monodevelop.com/Project/Index/41
http://sourceforge.net/projects/monodevelop.mirror/files/?source=navbar

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem too. I believe it's because the Haxe language binding doesn't currently support (MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio) version 4. And they don't currently seem to offer trunk builds, so we might be out of luck!
http://monodevelop.com/download/trunk_builds